# Cloud Dataflow executed successfully but not inserted data into Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a CSV file which contain header and data. I want to insert file(data) into Bigquery. I have written code to read file header and used for table/column mapping. I made it as dynamic file import(In Bigquery I have created one static empty table).

My cloud dataflow got executed successfully but data was not inserted into my Bigquery table. I am not sure what would be the problem.

I ran below code in Eclipse:

```
package com.coe.cog;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SimpleFunction;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableReference;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;

public class DemoPipeline_SameCodeProcess {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoPipeline_SameCodeProcess.class);

//Get Project,dataset & table
public static TableReference getGCDSTableReference() {
TableReference ref = new TableReference();
ref.setProjectId("myownprojectbqs");
ref.setDatasetId("DS_Employee");
ref.setTableId("tLoadEmp");
return ref;
}

//split input file with header and data sepearately
static class TransformToTable extends DoFn<String, TableRow> {
@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws IOException {
BufferedReader br = null;
     String line = "";
     String csvSplitBy = ",";
     Integer incFlg = 0;

     StringReader  strdr = new StringReader(c.element().toString());

     br = new BufferedReader(strdr);

     line = br.readLine(); //Header as FirstLine
     String[] colmnsHeader = line.split(csvSplitBy); //Only Header array

     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

         // Content of the file excluding header
         String[] colmnsList = line.split(csvSplitBy); 

         TableRow row = new TableRow();

         for (int i = 0; i < colmnsList.length; i++) {
           row.set(colmnsHeader[i], colmnsList[i]);
         }
       c.output(row);
     }
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

MyOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(MyOptions.class);

options.setTempLocation("gs://demo-bucket-data/temp");

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

PCollection<String> lines = p.apply("Read From Storage", TextIO.read().from("gs://demo-bucket-data/Demo/Test/MasterLoad_WithHeader.csv"));

PCollection<TableRow> rows = lines.apply("Transform To Table",ParDo.of(new TransformToTable()));

rows.apply("Write To Table",BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(getGCDSTableReference())
.withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
.withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER));

p.run();
}
}
```

**Input File Format(MasterLoad_WithHeader.csv):-**

---

ID,NAME,AGE,SEX
1,John,25,M
2,Smith,28,M
3,Josephine,22,F

[image: Dataflow Execution]

Comment: Review|Help and Improvement: displayed image

Comment: I feel this problem is happening because dataflow is running single dataset/file in multiple worker node, unable to read header as first record. so mapping is not happening.

Comment: Does the table already exist in BigQuery?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Graham Polley , Static table will be created manually before the execution of this Java file. Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: @KannanOn Clicking on graph Please Check that your Transformation is Giving some o/p or not it may happen in c.output the Tablerow is Empty. Because Every Step of Graph Shows Input and Output Ig O/p is 0 then You Need to Check your Transformation Logic

Comment: @Kannan could you check the logs of BigQuery job and give some additional information if you have any ? Maybe the problem comes from the fact that the names of CSV headers don't match the names of columns in BigQuery ?  Or if you've any other logs showing that the data is written to BigQuery, it could also help.

Comment: Hey, has the issue been resolved? Please share the solution, if the case.

Comment: @MonicaPC did you find a solution? I have the same issue, dataflow job executes correctly, no warnings, no errors, but data does not end up on bigquery

Comment: Hi Alessandro, 
Please open an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491268&template=1161126&pli=1) and provide your job ID.